# Elegant way to reduce/filter redundant sample data with bitcode

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to ask for ideas of an elegant(time saving) way to reduce redundant digitally sampled data. 
I got a .csv files with a structure like that:

```
time, data1, data2, data3
0.1, 1, 1, 0
0.2, 1, 1, 0
0.3, 1, 1, 0
0.4, 1, 0, 0
0.5, 1, 0, 0
0.6, 1, 0, 0
0.7, 0, 1, 0
0.8, 0, 1, 0
```

I want to reduce the incoming data in such manner that all unnecessary time steps are removed. E.g.

```
time, data1, data2, data3
0.1, 1, 1, 0 
0.4, 1, 0, 0
0.7, 0, 1, 0
```

The remaining data should just consist of the timesteps whenever the bitcode has changed.
I already implemented a method importing the csv file with **pandas** and using the corresponding *mask* and *compress* functions. But the way I implemented it is very time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If first column is index use:

```
df = df[df.ne(df.shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
      data1  data2  data3
time                     
0.1       1      1      0
0.4       1      0      0
0.7       0      1      0
```

If first column is not index:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df = df[df1.ne(df1.shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   time  data1  data2  data3
0   0.1      1      1      0
3   0.4      1      0      0
6   0.7      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach comparing with a shifted version:

```
df_ = df.loc[:, 'data1':]
df[~df_.eq(df_.shift()).all(1)]

   time  data1  data2  data3
0   0.1      1      1      0
3   0.4      1      0      0
6   0.7      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby`:

```
print(df.groupby(['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], as_index=False).first())
```